# Detecting array change in linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Getting a byte array like this [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0]

Does anyone know how to detect a change from 1 to 3 efficiently in linq?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to be more specific. What do you mean by "detect a change"? And what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: do you want the index where the first 3 appears after a 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `Linq`? you could achieve this with simple loop.

```
int previous = array[0];
for(int i=1;i< array.Length;i++)
{
    if(Math.Abs(array[i]- previous) > 1)  // use appropriate jump
    {
        //logic
    }   
    previous = array[i];
}
```

If you are looking for `Linq` solution, you could do this.

```
int previous = array[0];

array.FirstOrDefault(x=> 
      {
           var retValue = Math.Abs(x- previous) > 1;
           previous = x;
           return retValue;
      });
```

Comment: Do you think is better to use a loop instead a linq query?

Comment: yes, `Linq` is not the best to this case.

Comment: what about doing a select distinct: var list=arrayByte.Select(e => e).Distinct().ToList() and then loop it?

Comment: `Distinct` will find you distinct elements, but how do you identify hikes?

Comment: I dont know how log this array is. So I have thought to sort it with a **Distinct** Linq to short it. Then, probably I will be able to do it more efficienty because I will have less items to loop. <pre><code> bool

            var list=arrayByte.Select(e => e).Distinct().ToArray<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] == 1 && list[i + 1] == 3)
                {
                    change = true;
                }
            }</code></pre>

Comment: You could do that, but it comes with little expense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all change-indexes in the most efficient way:

```
List<int> changeIndexes = new List<int>();
for(int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    if(array[i] != array[i-1])
        changeIndexes.Add(i);
```

Linq is not the best tool when it comes to indexes.

If you want to find only the index where 1 changes to 3 modify the condition accordingly:

```
if(array[i] == 3 && array[i-1] == 1) ...  // break the loop if you only want to find the first
```